# Different borders in a single div

Tags: html, css, border, border-image

I am having a problem using css to have different borders in my div.
I need a card (div) that has "normal" solid border on the left, top and right sides of the div. However, in the bottom, I need a specific border image.

I am able to have the image in the bottom border OR the "normal" border on the three sides, but I do not know how to have both at the same time.

When I put the image, it goes to all borders.

I am using the following code to the bottom image border:

```
border-width: 0px 0px 32px 0px;
-moz-border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 repeat;
border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 fill repeat;
```

Do you know any way to have a normal solid border on the three sides and the image in the bottom border?

If I change the `border-width` to more than zero, appears the image, not the normal solid border.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the below answers if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was able to do this by adding a div inside another div.

```
.div-outside-class {
border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #e6e9ee;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.div-inside-class {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0px 32px 0px;
-moz-border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 repeat;
border-image: url(../images/bordas/Recorte.png) 31 25 33 26 fill repeat;
margin-bottom: -16px;
}
```

HTML code is something like that:

```
<div class="div-outside-class">
    <div class="div-inside-class>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:after` to simulate that effect.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  margin-left: -1px;
  background: white;
  display:block;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=2bb144720a66);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: I believe this will work as well. I did not use it because the other approach was easier to me. But that is a possible solution as well, I believe.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer.  That way people know that you have found a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border for bottom image first, then set for other sides.

```
border-image:url("http://example.com/image1.png");

/* setting borders for other sides */
border-top:1px solid #000;
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
```

Below it set for other sides top, right and left.